# General topology exercise 1

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathbb R$ be a set of all real numbers. For each $a\in \mathbb R$, define $L_a=\{x\in\mathbb R\mid x<a\}$ to be open left ray of real numbers.

Let $\tau$ consist of all possible open left rays together with $\varnothing$ and $\mathbb R$ and show that $(\mathbb R,\tau)$ is topological space.

Comment: That's a pretty vague question.

Comment: Where have you tried? You have to check couple of properties. Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Well, there are only two things to be checked: closed under binary intersections and closed under unions.

Comment: @Krish the first condition is verified but the union and intersection conditions are complicate

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $\emptyset,\mathbb{R}\in\tau$.

If $A\subset\tau$, you want to prove that $\bigcup_{X\in A}X\in\tau$. If $\mathbb R\in A$, then $\bigcup_{X\in A}X=\mathbb{R}\in\tau$. Otherwise, let $A^\star=\{X\in A\,|\,A\neq\emptyset\}$. Then $\bigcup_{X\in A}X=\bigcup_{X\in A^\star}X$. If $A^\star=\emptyset$, then $\bigcup_{X\in A^\star}X=\emptyset$. Otherwise, each element $X$ of $A^\star$ is equal to $(-\infty,a_X)$, for some $a_X\in\mathbb R$. Therefore\begin{align}\bigcup_{X\in A^\star}X&=\bigcup_{X\in A^\star}(-\infty,a_X)\\&=\begin{cases}\mathbb{R}&\text{ if }\{a_X\,|\,X\in A^\star\}\text{ has no upper bound}\\\left(-\infty,\sup_{X\in A^\star}a_X\right)&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}\\&\in\tau.\end{align}

If $A\subset\tau$ and $\tau$ is finite, you want to prove that $\bigcap_{X\in A}X\in\tau$. Has above, you can suppose, without loss of generality, that each $X$ is of the form $(-\infty,a_X)$, for some $a_X\in\mathbb R$. But then\begin{align}\bigcap_{X\in A}X&=\bigcap_{X\in A}(-\infty,a_X)\\&=\left(-\infty,\min\left\{a_X\,\middle|\,X\in A\right\}\right).\end{align}

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful

Answer (score 0):

You want to show this is a topology. So recall axioms of topological space:

1. The set and the empty set must be in the topology;
2. Arbitrary unions of elements of the topology must also be there;
3. Finite intersections of elements of the topology must also be there;

So with this in mind, we just go through them for $\tau$.

1. It is verified by definition, since $\emptyset,\mathbb{R}$ are included by hand;
2. Let $(U_\lambda)_{\lambda\in \Lambda}$ be a collection of elements of $\tau$. Let $U$ be their union. You want so show that $U$ is in $\tau$. This means that you must show $U$ is either $\emptyset,\mathbb{R}$ or an open left ray. If all $U_\lambda$ are empty then $U$ is the empty set and you are done. If some $U_\lambda$ is $\mathbb{R}$ then $U$ is $\mathbb{R}$ and you are done. To finish we can suppose without loss of generality that all $U_\lambda$ are open left rays.

   In that case $U_\lambda = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : x< a_\lambda\}$. Consider the set of upper bounds $A=\{a_\lambda : \lambda \in \Lambda\}$. If the set is unbounded, for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$ there is some $a_\lambda \in A$ such that $x < a_\lambda$. In that case, $x\in U_\lambda$ and hence $x\in U$. So in conclusion, when $A$ is unbounded, $ U = \mathbb{R}$ and so $U\in \tau$.

   On the other hand, if $A$ is bounded, there exists $a = \sup A$. We claim that $U = L_a$. Indeed, if $x\in U$ we have $x\in U_\lambda$ for some $\lambda\in \Lambda$ thus $x < a_\lambda$ and $x < a$, so $x\in L_a$. Conversely, if $x\in L_a$ we have $x < a$ and by definition of the supremum as the least upper bound there exists some $a_\lambda$ such tat $x < a_\lambda < a$. Thus $x\in U_\lambda$ and $x\in U$. So $U = L_a\in \tau$. In conclusion, covered all the cases, arbitrary unions of elements of $\tau$ are in $\tau$ and we are done verifying (2).
3. Now we verify $3$. Let $U_i\in \tau$ and consider $U_1\cap\cdots \cap U_n$. If they are all disjoint we have the empty set and we are done. If all of them are $\mathbb{R}$ we have $\mathbb{R}$ and we are done.

   Other than that, we can consider without loss of generality that we are dealing with a finite collection of open left rays. So that $U_i = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : x < a_i\}$. Pick $a = \min\{a_i\}$ which exists since we are dealing with a finite set. Then if $x < a$ we have $x < a_i$ and so $L_a\subset U_1\cap\cdots \cap U_n$. On the other hand if $x \in U_1\cap\cdots \cap U_n$ then $ x<a_i$ for all $a_i$ and $x < a$ for sure. Hence, $U_1\cap\cdots \cap U_n\subset L_a$. Thus $U_1\cap\cdots \cap U_n = L_a$ and the finite intersection is also in the topology. Having verified (1,2,3) $\tau$ is indeed a topology.